# Java Chat Server Connecting via NETCAT

Tags: java, chat, hostname, netcat

I'm trying to implement a JAVA UDP-based Chat server.
I need to implement a server that allows me to connect via netcat.
The main problem is that I must connect like this: (the run-example is this one):

> Server --> java ServerUDP 
>   Client --> nc HostName

How can I create a named Host? I mean, I can connect via:

```
nc -u localhost 7777
```

But if I would like to connect like this:

```
nc myServer
```

How should I implement it in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding an IP address to a domain name isn't related to your java server. You have to implement nothing.

Assuming you are using GNU/Linux, if you need to resolve a name locally to your pc you can simply edit /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1         localhost 
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX   service-name
```

If you need to resolve from every pc in your lan, you can setup a DNS server.
If you need to reach that node from everywhere, you need to buy a domain name from a DNS authority.

Whatever situation you are in, it has nothing to do with your Java code.